# How to create a physical folder in visual studio 2022

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I need help figuring out a way to create physical folders in Visual Studio 2022 so that they will appear in both file explorer and solution explorer. I have existing projects which sit inside solutions. I want to create two folders using Visual Studio, name them "dev" and "prod" and move existing projects to these folders.

I am using Visual Studio 2022, which does not have the option to add folders. I can create logical folders by right-clicking on the solution and selecting "New Solution Folder" but it doesn't appear inside file explorer.

Please let me know of any workaround to achieve the same. Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Just create them in Windows File Explorer then add them to your Solution in VS. e.g. Create a folder `dev` in Windows copy the files you want there. Then go VS create a new solution folder with same name `dev`, right Click this virtual folder add existing item then browse to add the item. This will give you the same structure in VS/Windows

Comment: @DawoodAwan, here I am adding csproject to that folder. When I select only the file "csproject" I am not able to add other related files for the same project

Comment: Project > Properties > Build > Output.  It is a per-configuration setting, add more configurations with Build > Configuration Manager > upper-left combo > New.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution Folders are a virtual hierarchy node to allow you to organize the solution items (projects or other files), without any association to what's on disk.  Some project types also offer similar functionality to organize the project contents separately from how they are saved to disk.

One way to work around this is to switch to Folder View.  However, this will unload your solution and projects so you'll have to toggle back and forth.

To switch to folder view, press this button:

[image: Showing the "Switch between solutions and available views" button on the Solution Explorer toolbar]

That will show you a list of the available solutions, with a Folder View in the list.  Selecting Folder View will switch Solution Explorer to showing the layout of files as they exist on disk.  You can then create the folders you want.  To switch back, press the button again, and select your solution from the list.

Some IDE features may not work in Folder View if they depend on the project being loaded.

Comment: Ok, But I am looking for a way to add a folder structure that needs to be the same in both file explorer and solution explorer

Comment: "without any association to what's on disk" - That's only half true, if you are in Solution View and select "Show All Files" at the top then files and folders under a project are displayed as the folder structure on disk is, and renaming or moving a file does the same action on disk. And you can right click and click "Include in Project" to add the file to the project file. Stuff not under a project though seems to be a solution view only without a way to synchronize it with the disk like the project files are.

Answer (score 0):

`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keybord`

Search for `Project.NewFolder` and set your desired keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Is this option will give you to create a new physical folder inside the solution? I can create a folder inside the project, but I am looking to create a physical folder inside solution explorer